# How do you convert an array of objects into an object of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having trouble converting an array of objects into an object of objects for my job. The company API is expecting the data in this format. Any help would be appreciated. Here is an example

Original

```
const array = [
 {
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 },
{
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 }
]
```

Final

```
const array = {
 {
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 },
{
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: that's not a valid object

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve that makes you think an array isn't good enough? (If your data is a list of objects, then there is rarely a reason to turn that into an object with key/value pairs)

Comment: Our API is expecting an object of objects for its response.

Comment: Maybe [convert an array to object](https://dev.to/afewminutesofcode/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-in-javascript-25a4) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use key/value pairs for object elements, but you can create an object from this array like this:

```js
const array = [
 {
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 },
{
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 }
]

let result = {}
array.forEach((el, idx) => {
  result['data_' + idx] = el
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Object will need keys.
An Object in Javascript is always { key:value, ...} (key-value pairs).

Therefor you will need to create these:

```js
const array = [
 {
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 },
{
  type: 'ITEM',
  info: {
   item_id: 'house'
  }
 }
]

const obj = array.reduce((o,e,i) => { return { ...o, ['item_'+i]: e }}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

change 'items_' to whatever suits your purpose.
If possible I'd suggest using an array here though.